# Нужно положить в NavigationDrawer фрагмент с ListView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Пытался представить код ListActiviry в виде фрагмента для последующего добавления в контейнер NavigationDrawerActivity. При добавление в контейнер возникает ошибка.
Как добавить такой фрагмент ?

Код фрагмента:

```
public class EventsFragment extends ListFragment {

    static DatabaseHelper sqlHelper;
    static Cursor userCursor;
    static SimpleCursorAdapter userAdapter;
    static Context context;
    static int day;
    static int month;
    static ListView listView;
    static DatePicker date;

    public EventsFragment() {
        this.context = MainActivity.context;
        sqlHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        try {
            sqlHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_events, container,false);
        date = (DatePicker)result.findViewById(R.id.date);
        listView = getListView();
        return result;

    }


    public static void updater(){
        day = date.getDayOfMonth();
        month = date.getMonth();
        try {
            sqlHelper.openDataBase();
            Log.i("DB-E", "open-s     " + sqlHelper.getReadableDatabase().toString());
            userCursor = sqlHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_MONTH + "=" + month + " AND " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DAY + "=" + day, null);
            Log.i("DB-E", "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_MONTH + "=" + month + " AND " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DAY + "=" + day);
            String[] eventsTitle = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_TITLE};
            userAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    userCursor, eventsTitle, new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, 0);
            listView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
        }
        catch (Exception ex){}

    }


    protected int getDay(String date){
        int r = 0;
        r=+getIntFromChar(date.charAt(0))*10;
        r+=getIntFromChar(date.charAt(1));
        return r;
    }

    protected int getMonth(String date){
        int r = 0;
        r=+getIntFromChar(date.charAt(3))*10;
        r+=getIntFromChar(date.charAt(4));
        return r;
    }

    protected int getIntFromChar(char c){
        switch (c){
            case '1' : return 1;
            case '2' : return 2;
            case '3' : return 3;
            case '4' : return 4;
            case '5' : return 5;
            case '6' : return 6;
            case '7' : return 7;
            case '8' : return 8;
            case '9' : return 9;
            case '0' : return 0;
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Код активности, из которой деле фрагмент:

```
public class EventsActivity extends ListActivity {

    DatabaseHelper sqlHelper;
    Cursor userCursor;
    SimpleCursorAdapter userAdapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events);

        Log.i("date", "" + DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.DATE_FIELD).format(new Date()));
        Log.i("date", ""+getDay(DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.DATE_FIELD).format(new Date())));

        int month = getMonth(DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.DATE_FIELD).format(new Date()));
        int day = getDay(DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.DATE_FIELD).format(new Date()));
        ListView listView = getListView();


        sqlHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            sqlHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            sqlHelper.openDataBase();
            Log.i("DB-E", "open-s     " + sqlHelper.getReadableDatabase().toString());
            userCursor = sqlHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_MONTH + "=" + month + " AND " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DAY + "=" + day, null);
            Log.i("DB-E", "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_MONTH + "=" + month + " AND " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DAY + "=" + day);
            String[] eventsTitle = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_TITLE};
            userAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    userCursor, eventsTitle, new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, 0);
            listView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
        }
        catch (Exception ex){}

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_events, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(EventsActivity.this,SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }

    protected int getDay(String date){
        int r = 0;
        r=+getIntFromChar(date.charAt(0))*10;
        r+=getIntFromChar(date.charAt(1));
        return r;
    }

    protected int getMonth(String date){
        int r = 0;
        r=+getIntFromChar(date.charAt(3))*10;
        r+=getIntFromChar(date.charAt(4));
        return r;
    }

    protected int getIntFromChar(char c){
        switch (c){
            case '1' : return 1;
            case '2' : return 2;
            case '3' : return 3;
            case '4' : return 4;
            case '5' : return 5;
            case '6' : return 6;
            case '7' : return 7;
            case '8' : return 8;
            case '9' : return 9;
            case '0' : return 0;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: В вопросе нет самого вопроса. Дополните его через кнопку "править" слева, внизу от тела вопроса.

Comment: 1. Не видно где вы пытаетесь фрагмент добавить. 2. Конструкторы для фрагментов не нужны и запрещены ибо не используются. 3. Контекст во фрагменте надо брать не из активити а вызовом метода `getActivity()` или (лучше) из аргумента метода `onAttach()`